# How to capture device input with ffmpeg in C?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I am trying to use ffmpeg in my C code to capture device input, like screen and audio record. I have looked through their official documentation and wiki, but the API documentation is not really well explained compare to the command line usage.

According to the documentation, if I want to record audio with alsa on linux I could, for example

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:<#card>,<#device> -t <seconds> out.wav
```

I want to use the C API to do the same thing, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your program is really for, but if there are no special restrictions, you can try calling shell commands in C:

```
/**
 * @brief exec_shcmd - execute a shell command via popen
 *(This function doesn't support write command now. such as 'echo "abc" > abc.txt')
 *
 * @para cmd_line - shell command string
 * @para read_buf - output string buffer after execute command
 * @para len - length of read buffer
 *
 * @return result of shell command execute
 * @retval 0 - success
 * @retcal -1 - failed
 */
int exec_shcmd(char *cmd_line, char *read_buf, ssize_t len)
{
    FILE *stream;

    if ((cmd_line == NULL) || (read_buf == NULL) || (len == 0)) {
        assert(0);
        return -1;
    }

    stream = popen(cmd_line, "r");
    if (stream == NULL) {
        assert(0);
        return -1;
    }

    memset(read_buf, 0, len);
    fread(read_buf, sizeof(char), len, stream);
    pclose(stream);

    printf("execute a shell command: %s", cmd_line);
    printf("shell command return: %s", read_buf);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the function I'm using, you can change it to suit your needs. And you can use it like this:

```
void main(void)
{
    char *cmd = "ls -al\n";
    char buf[500];
    int ret;

    printf("<-----------cmd exec------------->\n");

    ret = exec_shcmd(cmd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    printf("result(0 - success -1 - fail): <%d>\n", ret);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know this is a choice, but I don't see the reason to call shell when ffmpeg provides API for C. The only thing is that I don't know how to use those API functions.

Comment: Is there anything you need for the example program here:https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/examples.html

Comment: I looked at this before, but I did not find anything about how to capture pcm sampling.